# minimal example of how to export a jupyter notebook to pdf using nbconvert and PDFExporter()

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am trying to export a pdf copy of a jupyter notebook using `nbconvert` from within a notebook cell. I have read the [documentation](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html), but I just cannot find some basic code to actually execute the nbconvert command and export to pdf.

I was able to get this far, but I was hoping that someone could just fill in the final gaps.

```
from nbconvert import PDFExporter
notebook_pdf = PDFExporter()
notebook_pdf.template_file = '../print_script/pdf_nocode.tplx'
```

Note sure how to get from here to actually getting the pdf created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that I found an easy way to get around this is just using the command line magic: `!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --template pdf_nocode.tplx ../mgmt_notebook05092016.ipynb` but it still seems good to know how to use execute a pdf creation from the nbconvert api.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm no expert, but managed to get this working.  The key is that you need to preprocess the notebook which will allow you to use the `PDFExporter.from_notebook_node()` function.  This will give you your pdf_data in byte format that can then be written to file:

```
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
from nbconvert import PDFExporter

notebook_filename = "notebook.ipynb"

with open(notebook_filename) as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')

ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})

pdf_exporter = PDFExporter()

pdf_data, resources = pdf_exporter.from_notebook_node(nb)

with open("notebook.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pdf_data)
    f.close()
```

It's worth noting that the ExecutePreprocessor requires the resources dict, but we don't use it in this example.

Comment: It works fine.Thanks for the information.

I just have a problem with the outline of tables and code Cells.

Is it possible to remove code cells from the PDF?
How to repare this layout problem?

Thanks

Comment: Calling f.close() is not necessary since you are using a with block.

Answer (score 0):

Following is rest api that convert .ipynb file into .html
POST: `http://URL/export/<id>`
Get: `http://URL/export/<id>` will return a id.html

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from nbconvert.exporters import HTMLExporter

exporter = HTMLExporter()

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/export/*": {"origins": "*"}})
api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('path')
notebook_file_srv = '/path of your .ipynb file'

def notebook_doesnt_exist(nb):
    abort(404, message="Notebook {} doesn't exist".format(nb))


class Notebook(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        return make_response(render_template(id + '.html'), 200, headers)


    def post(self, id):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        notebook_file = args['path']

        notebook_file = notebook_file_srv + id + '.ipynb'

        if not os.path.exists(notebook_file):
            return 'notebook \'.ipynb\' file not found', 404
        else:
            nb_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(notebook_file))
            # dirname = os.path.dirname(notebook_file)
            output_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'templates')

            output_path = os.path.join(output_path, '{}.html'.format(nb_name))

            output, resources = exporter.from_filename(notebook_file)

            f = open(output_path, 'wb')
            f.write(output.encode('utf8'))
            f.close()
            return 'done', 201


api.add_resource(Notebook, '/export/<id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: OP asked for a PDF exporter in the context of a Jupyter notebook. You gave an HTML exporter in the context of a flask application.